# need help discovering unknown referrer fgbel_fzbvy

Tags: traffic

Every week I get some traffic from a mysterious referrer that I know nothing about: **fgbel_fzbvy**. I would guess that it's a bot, but I can't find any information about it. Does anyone out there have any information?

I have 3 requests within 2 seconds (see below) to different pages, so I think that's confirmation that it's a bot?

```
2023-09-03 15:00:48,169 request 1
2023-09-03 15:00:48,843 request 2
2023-09-03 15:00:49,257 request 3
```